# Selecting a managed switch with Linux, for use in mesh network project (batman-adv)

Tags: networking, wifi, embedded, dd-wrt

I am interested in trying out batman-adv to manage a mesh network comprised of point-to-point radios (mesh links) and cellular modems (gateways).

Each node would have one p2p radio, and some nodes would also have one cell modem.
All nodes would also have a device that uses the network (small embedded device with ethernet interface), so in total there are three ethernet devices.

In order to keep the power and size foot print small, I want to stay away from using a computer with three nics, and I was wondering if there are routers (no need to be wireless, 802.11 won't be used) that would be suitable (linux, access to all ethernet interface, can support batman-adv)

For example, maybe routers that support dd-wrt can have batman-adv loaded and used in such a manner?

Comment: I solved it here on ubuntu:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/205337/how-do-i-install-batman-adv-under-ubuntu-12-04-to-start-a-mesh-network

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point towards [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org).  While I don't know which hardware item would be best suited for your case, [many of the *not-too-low-spec'ed* devices are supported by OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start).

They've got a [B.A.T.M.A.N. wiki page](http://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/mesh.batman) and I [suspect](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/net/batman-adv/Makefile) `batman-adv` and `batctl` are prebuilt (i.e. installable via `opkg install batman-adv`).

The `open-mesh.org` people also give [instructions for building it with OpenWRT](http://www.open-mesh.org/projects/batman-adv/wiki/Building-with-openwrt/).

[Note that there are many projects and specialised forks in this area, better have a look around...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects)